# Visual Studio 2010 status bar in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, loops, c++-cli

In VS 2010 I'm trying to read a text file on button click and set that value as the status button value. The text file will always contain a single line with a number between 0 and 100. I'm trying to do this in C++/CLI because I'm familiar with C++ but this seems like a whole different lang! This is what I have but it causes the GUI to crash. I know it's the loops fault but I don't know why, what's the best (noob) way to approach this?

```
    while (result<100)
    {
            StreamReader ^read=gcnew StreamReader("Status.txt");                    
            String ^x=read->ReadLine();
            read->Close();
            Int32::TryParse(x, result);
            progressBar1->Value= result;    
    }
```

Comment: Why the loop? If the value is always less than 100 then it'll hung your app in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry if I phrased that misleading, I meant from 0 to 100.

Comment: No you didn't. Follow program flow: loop WHILE result is less than 100. But. It won't ever exit the loop because it can't be more than 100. Never. So your program will enter on an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, it is a very different language.  Another thing it does is that it doesn't just "crash", it gives you a good exception message.  You'll need to document it in your question.

Comment: Okay, I thought (100<100) would yield false and exit the while loop. When I run the program with a value of 100 in the file it works fine and appears to be breaking the loop, so I"m confused about the condition of the while loop then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said whether you're using WPF or WinForms for your GUI, but this answer applies equally to either.

If your while loop in in a button handler, that code is running on the UI thread. The UI thread is also responsible for redrawing the GUI. Since your button method isn't returning, it's never getting to the 'repaint' code, and the UI just stops.

You didn't mention what is writing those integers 0 to 100 to a file. If it's another thread in the same application, there are MUCH better ways of communicating the progress between threads.

I recommend that you replace that while loop with a `Timer` object of some sort. (There are appropriate classes, depending on whether you're using WPF or WinForms.) Set the interval to something like 500 milliseconds, start the timer when your background task begins, and stop the timer when it ends. In the timer method, don't have a while loop, just do it once.

Comment: David thanks for this answer this is defiantly what's going on by the GUI glitch's in text box. The file is updated by windows command line. I overestimated my skills in C++ carrying over to this. I'll try your timer method, thanks again.

Comment: David just wanted to say thanks again. The timer works perfect for the simple loop I want to run without creating a whole new thread, which I'm quite intimidated to do at my experience level.